# Force a <div> to stay in one place

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, a left and a right one. The left one takes up 70% and the right 30%. How do I make it so the stuff in the left one (with varied content) goes to the next line when it gets to 70%? Right now it just pushes my right div out of the way.

```
#left {
float: left;
width: 69%;
padding-left: 50px;
}
#right {
float: right;
width: 30%;
padding-right: 50px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to remove your padding.

```
#left {
float: left;
width: 70%;
}
#right {
float: right;
width: 30%;
}
```

[jfiddle example:](http://jsfiddle.net/KKt3U/)

If you need padding, add an internal div for padding.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have such extreme padding, the box model is being a bit screwed with so change it, also you should float *both* divs left:

```
#left {
float: left;
width: 70%;
padding-left: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#right {
float: left;
width: 30%;
padding-right: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gbqtQ/1/ (resize the result window to see if it suits you)

:)

Answer (score 0):

`padding & borer` add `width` to your `div` you can use `box-sizing` to force them not add width on it like this:

```
#left {
float: left;
width: 70%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #600;  
   padding-left: 50px;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/KKt3U/1/